# match cookie with element ID using each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, each

I have a bunch of cookies set that I want to match against the IDs of all elements on the page. Essentially, on page load iterate through dom and check if this element's ID value matches a cookie's value and do something to that element.

Here is my code so far.

```
<div class="event" id="event_1">

</div>

<div class="event" id="event_100">

</div>

<div class="event" id="event_47">

</div>
```

Assume there are cookies already set:

```
event_1, event_1, 30
event_100, event_100, 30 
event_47, event_47, 30
```

```javascript
$('.event').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id == readCookie('event_'+id+'')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }

    console.log(id);
    //returns event_1,event_100,event_47
});
```

I think I'm almost there. I think it has something to do with the var id and it returning a array. If I hard-code it to event_1 it works.

What should I be doing here? Thanks

Comment: You haven't told us about the problem, or why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Code formatting is super simple: Indent your code by four spaces (or select it and click the code button): http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: if you're iterating through all elements, why not do a `$(body).each()` than adding a class to every element?

Comment: What does `readCookie(...)` return? How does it work? There might be even a better way than iterating over all elements.

Comment: you could just do `var id = this.id;` instead of `var id = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: @Felix thanks for the tip. First time using Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id you are collecting already has the event_ part yet you add it when trying to read the cookie (attempting to read event_event_1 for example), I think it should be this instead

```
if(id == readCookie(id)){
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: without knowing what `readCookie` does, this is a great answer.

Comment: Wow I just did a head smack. Thank you so much!